# Correct order on accumulating rotations

Tags: rotation, quaternion

Suppose I have an Arcball camera that rotates up/down and sideways based on mouse input. After doing some research, I discovered that the correct way of calculating the new orientation is to do it the following way

```
// qy is a rotation (in quaternion) around the y-axis
// qx ~ around the x-axis
Quaternion orientation = (qy * old_orientation * qx);
```

However, I am not sure why switching the order of `qx` and `qy` introduces unwanted roll.

One answer from [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30644/how-to-keep-my-quaternion-using-fps-camera-from-tilting-and-messing-up) brushes on the subject.

The answer stated and I quote

> When working with Quaternions, order does matter, as it always does with 3D rotations. In my example, "Direction *= newRotation" is the same as "Direction = Direction * newRotation". But, with left and right rotations, we want it the other way around. This makes it not dependent on the up and down tilt, which causes roll.

Based on my understanding, `orientation` does the complete opposite of what they described. `qy` depends on `qx` since we apply `qx` to some vector first. What did I miss or what did I misunderstand?

Comment: [This previous Q&A may help build some intuition](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/39518) — I have some animated gifs showing sequences of rotations, and how multiplying on the left vs right means rotating around global vs local axes.

Comment: @DMGregory Your post does a brilliant job at explaining why we need to sperate the two rotations. But, I am still confused about why "Pitch Locally, Yaw Globally" is the order. Why does it stop working when we do "Yaw Locally, Pitch Globally"?

Comment: See the bottom example for that. Yaw locally, pitch globally is the order you want if you're manipulating a spinning globe, and you want it to always yaw around ITS north & south poles, but pitch toward/away from YOU (here taken as a fixed observer in global space). When controlling the viewpoint, you want to do the opposite: pitch around YOUR x axis (running from your left to right ear, for example), but yaw around the WORLD's y axis (parallel to the gravity vector)